# How to select one chech menu at one time in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I created a menu with checkbutton in my tkinter program but i wanted to select only one menu at one time below is code

```py
def menu(self):
        menubar = Menu(bg="black",fg="white")

        self.file_menu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save",command=self.Save)

        self.edit_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label="Undo",command=self.Undo)
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label="Redo",command=self.Redo)
        self.edit_menu.add_separator()

        self.edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut",command=self.Cut)
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy",command=self.Copy)
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label="Paste",command=self.Paste)
        self.edit_menu.add_separator()

        self.edit_menu.add_command(label="Find",command=self.Find)
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label="Replace",command=self.Replace)

        self.Run_menu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        self.Run_menu.add_command(label="Run",command=self.Run) 

        Language_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
        Language_menu.add_checkbutton(label="Python")
        Language_menu.add_checkbutton(label="Java")
        self.Run_menu.add_cascade(label="Language  ",menu=Language_menu)
        
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=self.file_menu)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=self.edit_menu)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Run",menu=self.Run_menu)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
```

i wants that if i will select python or java any one of them then other automatically got deselect
thanks in advance

Comment: If the options are mutually exclusive then you should use radio buttons instead. See https://python-course.eu/tkinter/radio-buttons-in-tkinter.php

Comment: It'a not what I am asking

Comment: My understanding is that you want to work so that if you check the 'Java' option, it de-selects the 'Python' option and if you select the 'Python' option, it de-selects the 'Java' option. This would mean you can only select one of the options. If so, you should use a radio button. If this is not what you want then please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't wanto buttons I wanted menu with check button

Comment: You can create a menu with radio buttons that will look the same but behave in the way you described. That is the purpose of the radio buttons.  See my answer for both examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use check buttons but want these to function such that clicking one unchecks the other then you can do so by creating variables to track the state of the check buttons and updating these as appropriate when clicked.

**Menu with check buttons**: Here is an example of this:

```
import tkinter as tk

parent = tk.Tk()

# create variables to track the state of check buttons
check_python = tk.BooleanVar()
check_java = tk.BooleanVar()


# handle the check buttons being clicked by unchecking others
def check_python_clicked():
    check_python.set(True)
    check_java.set(False)


def check_java_clicked():
    check_python.set(False)
    check_java.set(True)


# create and display the menu
menu_bar = tk.Menu(bg="black", fg="white")

run_menu = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)
language_menu = tk.Menu(run_menu)
language_menu.add_checkbutton(label='Python', variable=check_python, command=check_python_clicked)
language_menu.add_checkbutton(label='Java', variable=check_java, command=check_java_clicked)
run_menu.add_cascade(label='Language', menu=language_menu)

menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Run", menu=run_menu)

parent.config(menu=menu_bar)
parent.mainloop()
```

**Menu with radio buttons**: However, you can use radio buttons and achieve the same functionality with less code.  This would be a better approach in this case as your options are mutually exclusive:

```
import tkinter as tk

parent = tk.Tk()
menu_bar = tk.Menu(bg="black", fg="white")

run_menu = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)

language_menu = tk.Menu(run_menu)
language_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Python')
language_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Java')

run_menu.add_cascade(label='Language', menu=language_menu)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Run", menu=run_menu)

parent.config(menu=menu_bar)
parent.mainloop()
```